# convert a string url friendly slug in local language

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to convert a user input string into url friendly slug in my local language.

I have used laravel 5.2 and tried to use `str_slug($request->input('title'))`.

It can convert english string to slug  but for local language it returns empty string. My input will be in Bangla language.

Using `$request->input('title')`. I get bangla text but could not convert it into url friendly slug.

How can I solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Following Function.
I don't know it will work with local language or not. But you can try it.

```
public function createSlug($str, $delimiter = '-'){

    $slug = strtolower(trim(preg_replace('/[\s-]+/', $delimiter, preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9-]+/', $delimiter, preg_replace('/[&]/', 'and', preg_replace('/[\']/', '', iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $str))))), $delimiter));
    return $slug;

}
```

**OR**

You Can see here for your specific local language
http://code.google.com/p/php-slugs/

Answer (score 1):

i know this is old but you can use laravel [Str::slug()](https://laravel.com/docs/master/helpers#method-str-slug) helper

first parameter is the title

second parameter is the separator

third parameter is the language

example :

```
Str::slug($file->getClientOriginalName(), '-', 'bn');
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done this using jquery and it's working fine

```
$('input[name=title]').on('blur', function () {
    var slugElm = $('input[name=slug]');

    if (slugElm.val()) { return; }

    // slugElm.val(this.value.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z0-9-]+/g, '-').replace(/^-+|-+$/g, ''));

    slugElm.val(this.value.toLowerCase().replace(this.value, this.value).replace(/^-+|-+$/g, '')
        .replace(/\s/g, '-'));

})
```

And there is a solution for laravel.

http://killerwhalesoft.com/blog/make-laravel-slug-support-utf8-characters/

Comment: While there are multiple spaces it returns multiple dashes. something like 'my---name-is'.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using javascript. Suppose your text is "আমার সোনার বাংলা", the function will return "আমার-সোনার-বাংলা". It also removes multiple dashes.

```
function slugify(text) {
    return text.toLowerCase().replace(text, text).replace(/^-+|-+$/g, '')
        .replace(/\s/g, '-').replace(/\-\-+/g, '-');

}
```

Modified answer from @Salman Mahmud

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this**

```
 <input type="text" name="title" id="title">
 <input type="hidden" name="slug" id="slug">

$("#title").keyup(function(){
    var str = $(this).val();
    var txt = str.replace(/ /g,"-");
    $("#slug").val(txt.toLowerCase());
})
```

this will be produce such type result "আমার-সোনার-বাংলা" of  "আমার সোনার বাংলা"